# PIP throwing logging error in google COLAB

Tags: pytorch, google-colaboratory

I tried

[image]

resetting of runtime does not help. Anyone know how to fix? Thanks

Comment: You have added a `logging.py` module that shadows the one from the standard library, so your python installation is effectively broken. Remove `/usr/local/bin/logging.py`, either manually, or better by uninstalling the package containing it.

Comment: @hoefling I ran a script from https://medium.com/@meet_patel/how-to-ssh-into-google-colab-and-run-scripts-from-terminal-instead-of-jupyter-notebook-3931f2674258 to get ssh access to colab machine. Can you please have a look and see if anything in it is causing python installation breakage... Thank you.